# Where can I find a derivation of interplanar seperation of triclinic crystal structure?

Tags: solid-state-physics, resource-recommendations, crystals

The interplanar seperation for orthorhombic crystals is found in most books on introductory solid state physics (e.g. Kittel). I searched for interplanar seperation for other crystals(hexagonal,triclinic etc), and found a list of formulas in the wikipedia page for Crystal structure. Where can I found derivation of such complicated formulas for interplanar spacing?

Comment: It is all geometry, albeit more complicated than for a higher symmetry system.

Comment: Yeah I tried to do derive the results from first principals,drawing the diagrams, but I couldn't come up with the results given.